# How to make the Sonar maven plugin example work

Tags: java, maven, plugins, sonarqube

I am trying to get the sonar-checkstyle-extension-plugin to run on my local Sonar server.

Firts I built the plugin via maven. Then I copied the plugin-jar manually to the extensions\plugins-folder of the server. After that I started the server.
Then I built the java-maven-simple project and ran mvn sonar:sonar.

But the sonar-checkstyle-extension-plugin never gets executed. I followed the documentation on  codehouse.org ("Coding a Plugin") step by step.

What am I missing? Do I need to add the plugin-name in Sonar somewhere? Or do I need to add something to the plugin- or project-pom?

Comment: Could you post the link to the example?

Comment: Of course: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/zipball/master

Comment: Did you activate the rule 'Method Count Check' provided by the sonar-checkstyle-extension-plugin in the Quality Profile used to analyse the java-maven-simple project ?

Comment: @Freddy Mallet Yes I did.

Comment: How do you know that "the sonar-checkstyle-extension-plugin never gets executed" ? I have activate the rule "Method Count Check" and set the "maxMethodsCount" parameter to "1". I then ran a SonarQube analysis on  https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/sonar-runner/java-sonar-runner-simple and got 1 violation.